# how to check window state in Team developer?

Tags: guptateamdeveloper, centura

How to check window state(minimized,maximized etc) in Team developer ? Is there any built in function available for the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *SalGetWindowState()* function for checking window state. 
Function take only one argument which is the handle of the window to be checked.

```
If SalGetWindowState(windowhandle) = Window_Minimized
  Call VisWinShow(windowhandle, SHOW_Normal)
```

Please Note: VisWinShow() function sets visibility state of a window. Its first argument is the window handle and second argument can be SHOW_Minimized, SHOW_Normal, SHOW_Maximized or SHOW_Hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SalGetWindowState(hWndForm)` you can check any of the following states:

```
`Window_Invalid    ( Value = 1 )
 Window_Maximized  ( Value = 3 )
 Window_Minimized  ( Value = 4 )
 Window_Normal     ( Value = 5 )
 Window_NotVisible  ( Value = 2 )`
```

Of course if you are using Word automation, you can't refer to `hWndForm`, so in this case use:

`Set nState = iWord__Application.PropGetWindowState( )`

Other options are:

```
Set bIsMaximised = VisWinIsMaximized (hWndForm)
Set bIsMinimised = VisWinIsMinimized(hWndForm)
Set bIsNormal = VisWinIsRestored (hWndForm)
Set bIsValid = VisWinIsWindow(hWndForm)
```